# Check if a "string" is an existing device name and not a partition name

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, mount, devices, df

For example if I have an existing device variable `/dev/sda`, I want to verify that it is not the name of a partition but of the entire disk.
I have tried this:

```
[[ $(df --output=source "$var" 2> /dev/null | tail -n 1) = 'udev' ]]
```

but this returns true whether the `var='/dev/sda'` device is connected, or if the `var='/dev/sda1'` partition is not mounted.
So even if you combine the previous condition with the following:

```
if grep -sq "^$var " /proc/mounts; then ...
```

it would not be sufficient to say that it is a disk name and not a disk partition.

How can I check if a `string` is an existing device name and not a partition name?

Comment: What's the bigger picture here? What are you using this information for? There are other tools (`lsblk`, `findmnt`) for accessing block device information that might be simpler than trying to wrangle the output of `df`

Comment: Hi steeldriver, I remember you. `What are you using this information for?` To see if the parameter entered by a user is an existing disk (correct output) or an invalid disk or partition of an existing disk (incorrect output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lsblk` for this - specifically `lsblk -o type` should return either `part` (for a partition) or `disk` (for a whole block device).

So for example given:

```
$ lsblk /dev/sda
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   9.8G  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0 164.7G  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0  31.1G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0  15.3G  0 part /usr/local
└─sda6   8:6    0  17.7G  0 part /home
```

then

```
$ var=/dev/sda; lsblk -ndo type "$var" | grep -qF part && echo "is a partition"
$ var=/dev/sda1; lsblk -ndo type "$var" | grep -qF part && echo "is a partition"
is a partition
```

or

```
$ var=/dev/sda; lsblk -ndo type "$var" | grep -qF disk && echo "is a disk"
is a disk
$ var=/dev/sda1; lsblk -ndo type "$var" | grep -qF disk && echo "is a disk"
```

Comment: `if [[ $(lsblk -ndo TYPE "$var" 2> /dev/null) != 'disk' ]]; then <error code block>; fi`. Thank you @steeldriver, `perl` champion. ;-)

Comment: Haha thanks - I consider myself very much a novice with perl - my programming in it is usually - shall we say - *stochastic*

Answer (score 0):

Use `lsblk`:

```bsh
var="/dev/sda"

if lsblk "$var" &>/dev/null; then
   echo "Is a disk."
else
   echo "Is not a disk."
fi
```

If `"$var"` not a valid device, e.g. `var="/dev/sda1"`, `lsblk` will have a non-zero exit code.

---

To get output of all devices:

```bsh
lsblk -dnp --output NAME
```

Comment: `lsblk /dev/sda1` does not give an error but the correct output: `sda1   8:1    1  650M  0 part`. `echo $?` is equal to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mountpoint`.

From `man mountpoint`:

```
NAME
       mountpoint - see if a directory or file is a mountpoint

SYNOPSIS
       mountpoint [-d|-q] directory | file

       mountpoint -x device

DESCRIPTION
       mountpoint   checks   whether   the   given   directory   or  file  is  mentioned  in  the
       /proc/self/mountinfo file.
```

Comment: Output: `/dev/sda1 is not a mountpoint`. Output2: `/dev/sda is not a mountpoint`, it also doesn't answer my question.